# SQL Server 2014 sql mulitpart identifier cannot be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm still a neophyte when it comes to SQL Server. So, can somewhat direct me in why I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "CSetOrder.OrderItemID" could not be bound.

This is the script:

```
SELECT 
    OrderItem.OrderID
    , OrderItem.OrderItemID
    , OrderItem.DID
    , CSet.NNumber
    , OrderItem.Amount
    , OrderItem.Quantity
    , OrderItem.Quantity
    , CSetOrder.CSetOrderID
    , CSet.CSetID
    , CSet.Required
FROM 
    CSet
INNER JOIN 
    OrderItem ON OrderItem.OrderItemID = ClaimSetOrder.OrderItemID
INNER JOIN 
    CSetOrder ON CSetOrder.CSetID = CSet.CSetID
WHERE 
    OrderItem.OID = XXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the table *before* using it in the `on` clause.  So, rearrange the order of the conditions in the `FROM`:

```
FROM ClaimSet INNER JOIN
     ClaimSetOrder
     ON ClaimSetOrder.ClaimSetID = ClaimSet.ClaimSetID INNER JOIN
     OrderLineItem
     ON OrderLineItem.OrderLineItemID = ClaimSetOrder.OrderLineItemID
```

Note:  I would also recommend that you use table aliases to simplify the query construction:

```
FROM ClaimSet cs INNER JOIN
     ClaimSetOrder cso
     ON cso.ClaimSetID = cs.ClaimSetID INNER JOIN
     OrderLineItem oli
     ON oli.OrderLineItemID = cso.OrderLineItemID
```

This requires changing all the column references throughout the query.

Comment: That has resolved the error. It just returns no data now (any thoughts?). Ugghh. I will accept your answer as soon as it gives me the option. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The `JOIN` conditions look reasonable, so the conclusion is that no rows match the `WHERE` clause.